# Script compiles and strategy.entry condition is met but no trades are initiated in backtest

Tags: pine-script

Not sure why Tradingview isn't showing this strategy entering any trades - I use the same entry condition for an indicator that shows points at which the condition is met. Been trying to debug this for hours. Would appreciate any help here. Thanks!

````
strategy("Good news", overlay=true, margin_long=500, margin_short=100, initial_capital=100, calc_on_order_fills=true, calc_on_every_tick=true, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100)

periods = 144
multip = 5
volthreshMA = multip*ta.sma(volume[1], periods)

longCondition = (volume > volthreshMA and close > open)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    

//2% stop loss
stopCondition = strategy.opentrades.profit(0) < (-0.02*strategy.opentrades.size(0))
if (stopCondition)
    strategy.close("stop loss")

//take profit when profit is 80% of max profit during trade    
takeprofitCondition = ((strategy.opentrades.max_runup(0) - strategy.opentrades.profit (0))/strategy.opentrades.max_runup(0)) > 0.2
if (takeprofitCondition)
    strategy.close("take profit")```
````

Comment: ok - i figured out that i misread the documentation on the margin_long parameter which should have been 20 instead of 500 - long positions are now initiating.

also debugged the stop loss but not sure what is happening with the take profit

Answer (score 1):

Got it working!

```
//@version=5
strategy("Good news", overlay=true, margin_long=20, calc_on_order_fills=true, calc_on_every_tick=true, commission_type = strategy.commission.percent, commission_value = 0.07)

//recommended settings
//for 15min: 
//for 5min
//for 3min
//for 1min
periods = input(144,"Number of periods for MA")
multip = input(5, "Volume MA multiplier")


volthreshMA = multip*ta.sma(volume[1], periods)

longCondition = volume > volthreshMA and close > open
orderSize = strategy.equity/close
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, qty=orderSize)

//2% stop loss    
strategy.exit("stop loss", "long", loss = 200)

//take profit when price crosses under moving average
strategy.close("long", when = ta.crossunder(close,ta.sma(close,6)))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to close an order "stop loss", which does not exist.
I guess you are trying to exit the order "long". So that should be the 1st parameter in Strategy.close().

````
strategy("Good news", overlay=true, margin_long=500, margin_short=100, initial_capital=100, calc_on_order_fills=true, calc_on_every_tick=true, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100)

periods = 144
multip = 5
volthreshMA = multip*ta.sma(volume[1], periods)

longCondition = (volume > volthreshMA and close > open)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    

//2% stop loss
stopCondition = strategy.opentrades.profit(0) < (-0.02*strategy.opentrades.size(0))
if (stopCondition)
    strategy.close("long", comment="stop loss")

//take profit when profit is 80% of max profit during trade    
takeprofitCondition = ((strategy.opentrades.max_runup(0) - strategy.opentrades.profit (0))/strategy.opentrades.max_runup(0)) > 0.2
if (takeprofitCondition)
    strategy.close("long", comment = "take profit")```
````

Comment: I don't think this is the issue - I'm not using strategy.exit which requires a position ID to close the trade. strategy.close automatically exits all open positions. The problem I'm having is that the long position doesn't get initiated in the first place